# Count with database values php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a database with products like so:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | Name   | Price |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | Burger | 3,96  |
+----+--------+-------+
| 2  | Fries  | 1,49  |
+----+--------+-------+
```

I get an array of id's from JS into the PHP script and now I want to get the total price in a single variable.

I use to use the PDO method to fetch data, but I've only sent them through to my JS. How do I actually use that data in PHP instead?

```
    $get = $db->prepare("SELECT price FROM products WHERE id IN ('$idString')");
    $get->execute();
    $rows = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: I think you are talking about AJAX, look it up there are a million tutorials on the web

Comment: I'm not talking about AJAX, I just need to count with the data inside PHP. Everything else is working fine. Thank you anyway!

Comment: if the question's about doing additions/math, then use `SUM()`, *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: Could you show us your expected output, either coming directly from MySQL or in your PHP code?

Comment: *"...then, the answers started rolling in like oranges".*

Comment: You've got $rows array in php, what prevents you from further using it in PHP instead of echoing to JS?

Comment: Ok, if the user has chosen one of each product I'd like to simply add 3,96 and 1,49 together and store the value in an int. Nothing more. The PDO statement should get the prices from the Database.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us a little more of what is going on in your code we would understand what it is you are actully trying to do. Your description does not help us much

Comment: You can use [jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using prepared statements and supply any user data as separate arguments because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the total (without the rest of the data), you can do that in your SQL:

```
$get = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) as total FROM products WHERE id IN ($idString)");
$get->execute();
$row = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['total'];
```

Alternatively, you can iterate your rows and produce a total:

```
$get = $db->prepare("SELECT price FROM products WHERE id IN ($idString)");
$get->execute();
$rows = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $total += $row['price'];
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: And `'$idString'` (untouched from the original code in the question) is supposed to be the array of id's?

Comment: Thank you! I just ran this but I get error code 500, Internal Server Error back. The only change I did was that I included my connection file. Any clues?

Comment: And when I tested, I used idString as "1, 2"

Comment: Nice, Alvaro, you called it lol. I think you have bunk SQL with the single quotes around the `$idString` value (unless I bunked something up, which would be lame since this is so easy -.-) Updating answer.

Comment: I think you forgot to write FROM products WHERE id IN ($idString)");?

Comment: Either way, now I get a echoed "1".

Comment: Haha, there's no `WHERE`. I suppose I missed it because it sounded like "Everything else is working fine." Updated answer. It sounds like your further trouble may be because your price data isn't a `FLOAT` column?

Comment: I solved it, I had too many quotes. I though the ids were supposed to be a string between the parentheses. Thanks for everyones help! Especially Bitwise Creative and user1903535

Answer (score 2):

If u want to get the sum of all the price list you can simply add sum function in your query like

```
$get = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(price) FROM products IN ('$idString')");
$get->execute();
$rows = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows)
```

Hope this helps.